# Finding the limit of $\mathbb E |Y\sqrt n - 1| - |Y \sqrt n|$

Tags: probability, limits, solution-verification

Let $Y$ be a random variable taking values in $\mathbb R$. I'm trying to evaluate:
$$ \lim _{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb E \left|Y\sqrt n - 1\right| - |Y \sqrt n|$$

The expression inside the expectation is dominated by $1$, so we should be able to apply the dominated convergence theorem to bring the limit inside the expectation. Pointwise, the expression inside the expectation converges to $-\text{sign}(Y)$. So if $Y$ is distributed symmetrically about $0$ and has a density at $0$, then the limit evaluates to $0$

Have I applied the dominated convergence theorem correctly?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.